# How to serialize a xml node with text value and other child nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a xml like this:

```
<xmlRootNode>
    <levelOneChildNode>
        Some text
        <levelTwoChildNode>
            <levelThreeChildNode>More text</levelThreeChildNode>
        </levelTwoChildNode>
    </levelOneChildNode>
</xmlRootNode>
```

I can't change the xml format because my client wants this format. How I should create and decorate "levelOneChildNode" class for a correct serialization? I can't use XmlElement or XmlAttribute. The only way to do this than I've thought is put "Some text" as a XmlElement and make a

```
string.replace("<textNode>", string.empty).replace("</textNode>", string.empty)
```

with de serialized xml to remove de tag but this is a crapy solution.

Any ideas **without manual xml manipulation**?

Comment: Your client is wrong. This XML is invalid.

Comment: @user1681317 aside from the typo in the intended-to-be-closing tag for `levelTwoChildNode`, what's the probem?

Comment: xml element can not contain text value and child elements.

Comment: Nope, my bad. It can :)

Comment: @user1681317 In fact, that weird xml format passes WC3 validation tool. I think as you but my client is disagree XD

Comment: @AakashM You are right! Fixed

Comment: @Alberto copy your xml, then go to VS Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes and you will get classes hierarchy for your xml. Then you should be able to serialize/deserialize it with XmlSerializer.

Comment: @user1681317 I will try that. Sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options, both of them related to manual xml-manipulation:

1. Use
   [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)
   to write elements one by one.
2. Fill general-purpose
   [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx),
   and save it.

Answer (score 0):

> Set/Retrieve/Append/Create XmlNotes (values):

```
//file name
string filename = @"d:\temp\XMLFile2.xml";

//create new instance of XmlDocument
XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();

//load from file
_doc.Load(filename);

// Change text in xml
XmlNode node= _doc.SelectSingleNode("xmlRootNode/levelOneChildNode"); // [index of user node]
node.InnerText = value;
_doc.Save(@"path");

// Retrive value from xml
XmlNode node = _doc.SelectSingleNode("xmlRootNode/levelOneChildNode/levelTwoChildNode/someAttribute");
string value = node.InnerText;

// read or write to more elements
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("xmlRootNode/levelOneChildNode/levelTwoChildNode"))
{
    string data= node.SelectSingleNode("someAttribute").InnerTex; // get value of someAttribute.

    node.InnerText = value;
} 

// Append Note to levelOneChildNode Note 

// Create second node
XmlNode secondNode = doc.CreateElement("SecondLevelNode");
secondNode .InnerText = "This title is created by code"

XmlNode firstNode= _doc.SelectSingleNode("xmlRootNode/levelOneChildNode");
firstNode.AppendChild(secondNode );
_doc.Save(@"path");
```

Comment: Serialize the xml document and then make manual xml manipulation is an option but if there is a way to do this without editin the serialized xml, better.

Comment: But why doing that if this is a simple and easy solution?